# Docker Toolbox for Windows, Container is not accesible on the host

Tags: docker, toolbox

I am new and working on Docker on my Windows Machine. I got toolbox installed on my machine well and ran a container, see below:

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
cea8e6cf92b5        seqvence/static-site   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->443/tcp   competent_goodall
```

Now, this is a Linux container running on a Oracle VM on my windows machine. After this I expect to do a http://172.17.0.2:32769 on my windows machine and get a web page running on Ngnix server.

Here is the container inspect:

```
"Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "81d64a885b80a000f3b91e9959acf125b170b7acb11a918bf77bf7fa3fea3ae1",
                    "EndpointID": "6cf13c7007539f0b31c6d8da52844477f13e1debd84a8f3e2ec63ee140e90014",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
```

I am not sure if any more details would be needed to understand the problem, so please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try either of the following,

```
http://localhost:32769
http://(ipv4 of your windows machine):32769
```